# Direct Sum and Set Difference.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, direct-sum

Suppose a finite dimensional vector space V is the direct sum of two subspaces $U_1,U_2$. Then $(V-U_1 )\cup$ $\{$ $\textbf{0}$ $\}$ $=$ $U_2$.
How do I show this?

I tried breaking it into the following cases:

(1)$U_1=U_2$ $=$ $\textbf{0}$

(2) Without loss of generality, $U_1$ is the zero vector, while $U_2$ contains atleast one non-zero vector.

(3) Both, $U_1$ and $U_2$ are non-zero.
The difficulty im encountering is with the third case. If both are non-zero then $U_1$ $\neq U_2$. 
If I take an arbitrary element in $(V-U_1) \cup$ $\{$ 0 $\}$ then I can break it into cases:

$x \in V- U_1$ and $x$ is the zero vector.
The latter case is trivial.
If $x\in V-U_1$ then $x\in V$, which is the direct sum of $U_1$ and $U_2$ and so $x=u_1+u_2$ for some $u_1$ in $U_1$ and $u_2$ in $U_2$. How do I proceed with this case?

Cases 1 and 2 are easy. I'm only wondering about the third case.
By $V-U_1$ I mean the set difference.

Comment: In case (1) you have $V = \{0\}$. In case (2) you have $V = U_2$. Just saying.

Comment: @amsmath As mentioned, i'm not having issues with case (1) and (2).

Comment: If $V-U = \{v-u : v\in V,\,u\in U\}$, then the claim is false.

Comment: @amsmath I meant the set difference.

Comment: Then it's even more false.

Comment: @amsmath what would be a counterexample?

Comment: Almost everything. Choose for example $V = \mathbb R^2 = U_1\oplus U_2$, where $U_j = span\{e_j\}$ with $e_j$ being the $j$-th standard basis vector. Now what is $V\setminus U_1$ geometrically?

Comment: @amsmath $\mathbb{R}^2-\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Exactly, it's $\mathbb R^2$ without x-axis. Is that equal to $U_2$? Is it a vector space at all?

Comment: @amsmath No, as it doesn't contain the zero vector.

Comment: Right. So it's not $U_2$. And even when you add the zero vector, it's not. It's much too large.

Comment: @amsmath This has clarified it. Thank you so much.